# Phpdesktop running codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, phpdesktop

I'm using PHPDesktop for my project. My application was developed in codeigniter. Everything was fine, then I changed to phpdesktop, I did some configurations but only the first page is working, when I change to another page, only shown a blank page with no errors, some ideas?

Comment: is error reporting on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Codeigniter example configuration for phpdesktop: https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/PHP-frameworks-support#codeigniter

Also check debug.log file or enable debug console in settings.json.